# Use wildcard SSL subdomains with a Windows Azure ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, ssl, azure, wildcard-subdomain

I have the following scenario and I need help to deploy it to Windows Azure.

I have the following ASP.NET site that routes customers based on the first part of the DNS name:

https://customer1.mysite.com

https://customer2.mysite.com

https://customer3.mysite.com

...

https://customerN.mysite.com

I have a wildcard SSL certificate with the following subject name *.mysite.com

What I have to do? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a Web Role or a Web Site?

Comment: @SandrinoDiMattia One Web Role for Multiple Web Sites.

Answer (score 1):

Just upload it to the portal and use it like any other SSL certificate. I did it myself and it worked with no problems.
General info about SSL and Azure can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff795779.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply: but how configure third level domains?

Comment: You need to setup this on your DNS, like you set the mysite.com to point to mysite.cloudapp.net. This is not really related to Windows Azure

Comment: Yes. But I have single Web Role for multiple Web Sites, how 
achieve it? Thanks

Comment: Hm, that means you have all sites on the same mysite.cloudapp.net domain, but on different ports? CNAME can't redirect to a different port and i currently don't see workaround for this.

Comment: Your suggeston is use different Web Role for different subdomain (so one for aaa.mysite.com, another for bbb.mysite.com) and use the same wildcard certificate for all Web Role?

Comment: In fact, you can redirect all of the subdomains using CNAME to yoursite.cloudapp.net and then in your code of site residing at yoursite.cloudapp.net on port 443, read request URI and handle routing of the requests to the particular site

Comment: If splitting the application to multiple roles is not a problem, you could than easily redirect with CNAME a.mysite.com to mysitea.cloudapp.net and b.mysite.com to mysiteb.cloudapp.net. Notice that you can't CNAME a wildcard, you need to specify concrete subdomains

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20531/discussion-between-andrea-and-pedala)